# Constructing an $11$ digit sequence with $8$ even digits

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can you construct an $11$ digit sequence where each digit can be repeated, and we use $8$ even digits?
The choices of digits are $1,2,3,\ldots,9$.

This is my attempt:
There are $4$ choices of even digits, and we want $8$ of them... $4^8$ ways.
There are $5$ choices of odd digits, and we want $3$ of them.... $5^3$ ways.
Then, choose the spots for the even digits... $\binom{11}8$ ways
(and the odd digits will fall into place after distributing the even digits).

So total is
$\binom{11}8 \times 4^8 \times 5^3$.
However, I'm unsure if my reasoning is correct at all.
My query is that I thought that $4^8$ and $5^3$ already orders them for us... so no need for $\binom{11}8$.

Comment: Do you allow first digit of the sequence to be $0$?

Comment: No, sorry I will add that in

Comment: Hi, just checking, can $0$ appear anywhere in the digit besides the first place?

Comment: Sorry I have edited the OP before to say that the permissible digits are $1,2,\ldots,9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is correct. But it may help if you think as follows.

First, choose the spot where you want to place even numbers.
Second, place the even numbers.
Third, place the odd numbers.

You are doing the task by steps. So multiplication principle holds.

Comment: The first step can also be interpreted as "place odd numbers" in $\binom{11}3$ ways right?

Comment: @Natash1 Yes. But then you can think of second step as placing odd numbers and third step as placing even numbers.

Comment: Yes and incidentally you proved that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Comment: Thanks! So using the odd numbers first,  
$\binom{11}3$ predetermines the (unarranged) spots we choose for the odd numbers. $5^3$ will then pop in our odd digits for these spots (and arranges them), and then there are $\binom{8}8$ spots for even digits, and then we place the even digits in $4^8$ ways?

Comment: We use $\binom{11}3$ instead of $P(11,3)$ because the $5^3$ will take care of the arranging part right?

Comment: That's correct. The first step is just find the spot and no arrangement is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Remark: OP's answer with the restriction that $0$ is excluded is correct. I was answering the question based on the assumption that only the first digit cannot be $0$ and it might appear elsewhere.

Note that there are $5$ even digits.

Case $1$: The first digit is even.

In that case we have $4$ options for the first digit.

After which, we can pick $3$ places to put the odd numbers.

$$4\binom{10}{3} 5^75^3$$

Case $2$: The first digit is odd.

In that case we have $5$ options for the first digit.

After which, we can pick $2$ places to put the odd numbers.

$$5\binom{10}{2} 5^85^2$$

Summing them up to the answer.

Comment: 5 even digits ? 0 is not included.

Comment: ooo, let me clarify something with OP. I didn't see that earlier. I wonder if $0$ can appear anywhere besides the first place.